# Python library requests open the wrong page

Tags: python, python-requests

I try to open a html page with python requests library but my code open the site root folder and i don't understand how solve the problem.

```
import requests

scraping = requests.request("POST", url = "http://www.pollnet.it/WeeklyReport_it.aspx?ID=69")

print scraping.content
```

Thank you for all suggestion!

Comment: Well the link itself opens the main site, that's the problem most likely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see easily that the server is redirecting to the main page.

```
➜  ~  http -v http://www.pollnet.it/WeeklyReport_it.aspx\?ID\=69
GET /WeeklyReport_it.aspx?ID=69 HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Host: www.pollnet.it
User-Agent: HTTPie/0.9.3



HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Content-Length: 131
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Sun, 07 Feb 2016 11:24:52 GMT
Location: /default.asp
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="%2fdefault.asp">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

---

On further checking, it can be seen that the web server uses session cookies.

```
➜  ~  http -v http://www.pollnet.it/default_it.asp

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 9471
Content-Type: text/html; Charset=utf-8
Date: Sun, 07 Feb 2016 13:21:41 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDSQTSTAST=PBHDLEIDFCNMPKIGANFDNMLK; path=/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

It means that every time the *main page* is visited, the server sends a "Set-Cookie" header, which instructs the browser to set certain cookies. Then every time the browser asks for a Weekly Report, the server validates the session cookie.

Normally. `requests` package does not save cookies in between requests, but to do the scraping, we can use a `Session` object which will save the cookies in between page requests.

```
import requests

# create a Session object
s= requests.Session()

# first visit the main page
s.get("http://www.pollnet.it/default_it.asp")

# then we can visit the weekly report pages
r = s.get("http://www.pollnet.it/WeeklyReport_it.aspx?ID=69")

print(r.text)

# another page
r = s.get("http://www.pollnet.it/WeeklyReport_it.aspx?ID=89")
print(r.text)
```

But here is some advice - the web server may only allow opening of a fixed number of pages (maybe 10, maybe 15) with a certain `Session` object. Either immediately validate the results of `r.text` each time (maybe check the length of the request body to ensure it is not too small), or create a new `Session` object, for every 5 or 6 pages.

More info on Session objects [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects).

Comment: Thank you! there is a trick to solve problem? if i navigate in chrome i arrive at the resource in 3 steps:
http://www.pollnet.it/default_it.asp -> http://www.pollnet.it/ReportRegional_it.aspx?ID=27 ->
http://www.pollnet.it/WeeklyReport_it.aspx?ID=69

Comment: @SocraM which page do you want to access?

Comment: I need to access to Firenze city data.
In chrome i select link "Toscana" Region = pollnet.it/ReportRegional_it.aspx?ID=27 , and then click on "FI1" for  
Firenze City =  pollnet.it/WeeklyReport_it.aspx?ID=69